# Приветствую! Нужна срочная помощь по боту для дискорда

Tags: discord.py

Как прописать в коде что бы конкретная роль могла использовать команды mute/warn/ban/unban/unmute?
Так же хотел бы узнать, как можно сделать так, что бы при бане человек не вылетал с сервера, а просто получал роль Banned?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтобы могла выдавать определённая роль используйте

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role(либо ид роли, либо название в ковычках)
```

А чтобы выдавать роль, используйте такой код:

```py
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason: int)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=ид роли)
    member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'Пользователь {member} получил блокировку!')
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Если я вам помог, отметьте, пожалуйста, мой ответ. Галочка справа от текста